# NGXS Forms - How to handle nested form components

Tags: angular, ngxs

I've got a user profile form with multiple steps, i.e. a wizard. On Submit/Save, the entire user profile form has to be submitted to an API
I'm using NGXS and NGXS Forms.

At the moment I have implemented the UI as a single Angular Reactive Forms and a single state property `form`, the model is of the type the API expects. There is a component for each step, but they all use the same `form`.
The big problem with this approach is that I can't detect whether the fields on a step are valid or not, I can only detect if the entire form is valid.

To solve this, I think I have to create multiple Angular forms. However, I can't bind them all to the same state property `form`, as on each step I only have a subset of properties.

So, my thinking now is to create a form property in my state for each step, each with its own interface for the properties it stores. Then, I can create a selector that will return  the entire object I can submit to the API.

In code, currently:

```
form: {
  model: UserProfileDto,
  ....
}
```

Proposal:

```
personalDetailsForm: {
model: PersonalDetailsModel, 
},
workDetailsForm: {
model: WorkDetailsModel
}

@Selector(ProfileDetails)
profileDetails(state: ProfileState) {
  return {...state.workDetailsForm.model, ...state.personalDetailsForm.model}
}
```

Is this the way to go or is there an easier approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very opinion question, but I can share my thoughts.

In parent component I will create separate form for every step:

- it helps to write validation rules for every step;
- you can check, is valid/invalid form in every step
- in case, if you store it in parent component, you can write logic for switching between steps(e.g. not allow to go to another step in case of current step is invalid)

```
export class Component {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.workDetailsForm = this.buildWorkForm();
    this.personalDetailsForm = this.buildPersonalForm();


    // and through merge + valueChanges you can get the last object at any time
    merge(
      this.workDetailsForm.valueChanges,
      this.personalDetailsForm.valuesChanges  
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.profileDetails = {
        ...this.workDetailsForm.value, 
        ...this.personalDetailsForm.value
      };
    });

    // here you can check, that the whole form is valid
    merge(
      this.workDetailsForm.statusChanges,
      this.personalDetailsForm.statusChanges  
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.isFormValid = this.workDetailsForm.valid && this.personalDetailsForm.valid;
    });
  }


}


<app-step-work-details
 [form]="workDetailsForm"> </app-step-work-details>

<app-step-personal-details
 [form]="personalDetailsForm"> </app-step-personal-details>
```

Comment: Again thanks @Slawa Eremin. I've implemented it based on your suggestions :)